# Postgres Case Insensitive in IN operator?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-insensitive, sql-in

My Sample Sql is

```
select * from fruits where name in ('Orange','grape','APPLE','ManGO',etc....);//
```

> Is possible to include ilike or ~* in IN Operator in Postgres?

My solution is

```
select * from fruits where upper(name) in 
(upper('Orange'),upper('grape'),upper('APPLE'),upper('ManGO'),etc....);
```

i think it is not correct method, Please let me know any optimal solution for this case

Comment: You can apply `LOWER()` to the `name` and all values as well to compare in a case insensitive manner.

Comment: yes but all values are not in lowercase

Comment: you meant like lower(name) in lower('Orange','APPLE')...?, I tried this it is not working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try to use `ILIKE` with `ANY`

```
SELECT * 
FROM fruits 
WHERE name ILIKE ANY(array['Orange', 'grape', 'APPLE', 'ManGO']);
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c5f720588ea78695ab9812754c55dacb)